# How to get rid of unwanted shading after Bevel

Tags: shaders

I need to make an object with two types of rounded edges through Bevel (Ctrl+B).
A large rounding of 6 segments, and a small rounding of 3 segments.
But I get some strange, unwanted shading. Such as shown in the screenshot.
I even tried to add a small rounding through the Bevel modifier, but this shading still appears.

[image]

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong? Why do things like this happen in such simple geometry? How to get rid of this unwanted shading?
Wireframe:
[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the wireframe?

Comment: Alexandre I just added a screenshot of the wireframe to the start post.

Comment: Looks like you've created an n-gon somewhere.  You can try Auto-Smooth or inset the face to create a ring of quads around this face

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the issue is you have a big n-gon (a face with more than 4 edges). This is usually not good practice and can sometimes lead to shading issues like this. The N-gon plus the bevel is making blender a little 'confused' on how it should smooth the shading.

Here I have replicated the issue:
[image]

Notice how this face has many edges.
[image]

A simple way to prevent this is by creating a new edge loop by insetting the face, creating a "buffer" for the smoothing. Like this:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Wow Alexander, thank you very much. Live and learn.